# add text to image php

Tags: php, html, image

I want to allow the user to insert to texts and add it to an image then download the image 
locally everything works perfect but when I upload the code to the server it doesn't work 
any ideas??

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="process.php"> 
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
        <br>  <br>
        <input type="text" name="username2"/>
        <br>  <br>
        <input type="submit" name="subpic" />
    </form>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['name'])&&isset($_GET['x'])) {
   $file = " ".$_GET['name']."".$_GET['x'].".jpg";
echo "<a href='process2.php?name=".$file."'>download</a> "; 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

process code is

```
<?php
$rImg = ImageCreateFromJPEG("doctor.jpg"); 
$cor = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 255, 0, 0);
$user = $_POST['username']; 
$user2 = $_POST['username2'];  
$font = 'roboto.ttf';
imagettftext($rImg, 39.5, 0, 155, 719, $cor, $font, $user);
imagettftext($rImg, 39.5, 0, 155, 780, $cor, $font, $user2);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($rImg, " ".$user."".urldecode($_GET['x']).".jpg");
header('location:main.php?name='.$user.'&x='.$_GET['x'].'');   
?>
```

and process2 code is:

```
<?php
$name= $_GET['name'];

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($name) . "\";");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: image/jpeg');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($name); //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you've missed the process2 code from your question